# Replacement of x:Type

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

whats the replacement of x:Type, for example I have:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <ia:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="DoubleTapped" SourceObject="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
      <ia:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="IncrementCount" />
    </ia:EventTriggerBehavior>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

How to replace it in the *SourceObject* Definition?

Comment: I don't quite get it what is your problem here. You must write a little more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's currently just `{Type ns:Name}`, i. e. without x: prefix.

Comment: Yep, but the next version will be using Portable.Xaml and it will move back to `x:Type`.